# Blueman No adapters found

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, bluetooth

I run this command:

```
uname -r; lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
```

this is the output:

```
4.15.0-43-generic
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0e8d:763f MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1ea7:0066  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e084]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7630e
    Kernel modules: mt7630e
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 70:77:81:79:E9:5A  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 128:2
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:580 acl:0 sco:0 events:31 errors:0
    TX bytes:371 acl:0 sco:0 commands:31 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0x8f 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x5b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 

[    0.024000] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[   14.784186] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   14.784210] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.784214] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.784215] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.784219] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.479970] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[   34.672247] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   34.672249] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   34.672252] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1536.260508] usb 1-6: device firmware changed
[ 1539.411872] Firmware file "mt76x0.bin" Found 
[ 1541.312165] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

The machine is an ASUS laptop, using Xubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

I installed the drivers for the wifi (MT7630E) and somehow they work (sometimes I need to reinstall them) but I was never able to get the bluetooth running, can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: What happens if you `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`

Comment: Hi @Jeremy31, thanks, this is the output: `Can't init device hci0: Invalid request code (56)`

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/wiki/Get-bluetooth-working-in-Linux-kernel--with-mt7630e) guide but I don't understand what it means by "cd to your preferred build dir". What directory is the guide talking about?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409396/unable-to-use-bluetooth-on-my-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put a patch based on what you found on my github, to install do

```
sudo apt install dkms git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/newbtfix-4.15.git
sudo dkms add ./newbtfix-4.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
```

Check results for `mokutil --sb-state` if it says Secure Boot is enabled, then Secure Boot will need to be disabled when you reboot, if it says Secure Boot disabled, mokutil not installed, or system doesn't support EFI variables, just reboot

Comment: ```sudo dkms install btusb/4.0

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
'make' all KVER=4.10.0-38-generic....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for btusb: 4.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.10.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/btusb/4.0/build/make.log for more information.```

I am not an expert on this matter. So I will leave you with this.

Comment: @JaydeepW the 4.10 kernel is EOL, install 4.15